# How can I draw a dynamic pie graph like this one in Android?

Tags: android, pie-chart

What is the easiest way to draw a pie graph like this one without using any third party libraries?

[image]

Comment: Make your own view or compound view. That's not an easy job but that's the way it's done. If you want to avoid any third party libraries.

Comment: Try the Canvas.drawArc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas.drawArc()` is the way to go.

Sample using 3 distances:

```
float distanceA = 20.0f;
float distanceB = 30.0f;
float distanceC = 40.0f;

float distanceTotal = distanceA + distanceB + distanceC;

/* Calculate the percentage that each distance represents out of the whole. That percentage represents the fraction of the the arc. */

float percentageA = distanceA/distanceTotal;
float percentageB = distanceB/distanceTotal;
float percentageC = distanceC/distanceTotal;

// Now draw the arc. For our bounds, just use a 40 X 40 
// rectangle, but change it for your dimensions.
RectF bounds = new RectF(0.0,0.0,40.0,40.0);

float startAngle = 0.0;
float angleA = percentageA * 360.0f;
float angleB = percentageB * 360.0f;
float angleC = percentageC * 360.0f;

// Draw the arc representing distanceA:
paint.setColor(colorA)
canvas.drawArc(bounds, startAngle,
                        angleA, true, paint);

/* Next arc will be drawn starting at the point where the arc representing distance A ends */
startAngle+=angleA;
paint.setColor(colorB);
canvas.drawArc(bounds, startAngle,
                        angleB, true, paint);

startAngle+=angleB;

// And so on for angle C. Adjust the stroke width on // the paint object to increase your arc thickness.
```

Yesterday implemented a circular pie-graph like feature that draws the segments as the user scrolls. Can refer to my github here. The FlashShapeView.java class has examples for drawing different shapes.
 https://github.com/jdgreene2008/android_custom_views/blob/master/CustomUiComponents/app/src/main/java/com/jarvis/dragdropresearch/views/FlashShapeView.java

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use MpAndroidChart.